# Angularjs - New layout file in UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

**My project structure**

```
js
views
 -dashboard.html
 -inbox.html
 -messages.html
 -home.html
includes
 -header.html
 -footer.html
 -aside.html
index.html
login.html
```

All my views are using index.html as the layout file which is containing `<div ui-view></div>`

```
 $stateProvider

            .state ('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
            })
            .state ('inbox', {
                url: '/inbox',
                templateUrl: 'views/inbox.html'
            })
```

I would to like use login.html as the new layout file for my login/register pages. How can I do this?

Comment: index.html contains your js and css?

Comment: Both Index and login has js and css. Index.html has more vendor CSS which I don't want in login

Comment: You can achieve this with the approach I have specified below

Comment: Is the solution clear and meets your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is create nested states.

```
// For index pages
.state ('index', {

                templateUrl: 'index.html'
            })
.state ('index.home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
            })


// For login
.state ('login', {

                templateUrl: 'login.html'
            })
.state ('login.register', {
                url: '/register',
                templateUrl: 'views/register.html'
            })
```

Now in both index.html and login.html you need to have . As they both will enact as independent layouts for different set of pages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried this but still login view is loaded inside index.html layout

Comment: It has to work. Can you share me your code? A plunker?

Comment: login.html itself loaded inside index.html. Wait let me create a plunker

Comment: Ok. I will be waiting.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/FjvLKIxab0x1huen07HV?p=preview I think it's working here but not in my projec.t I'm trying to fix that

Comment: Ok. Please share me with the updates. You can mark my answer as accepted when it works for you

Comment: Cannot work, check you plunker, menus are showing twice on clicking any of them, it means always rendering in index page

Comment: @AliAdravi I will check in a while

Comment: @AliAdravi - I have not created any plunker for the same? Can you please let me know which plunker you are referring to?

Comment: See the comment from Body  
plnkr.co/edit/FjvLKIxab0x1huen07HV?p=preview

Comment: Well that was posted by someone else and I have neither responded to the plunker nor corrected it. Hence,  it would be harsh to downvote for this reason. Additionally,  if you want to fix the plunker,  please post it as a new question.